# Linking to specific jquery tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have looked high and low for an answer to this. The issue I am running into is there are certain style characteristics to my tabs that need to stay intact. The following is the page I am working on:

http://nextadagency.com/theta/services.html

I am trying to create links (on a separate page) to each of the tabs. When the "Services" page loads, have it load the selected tab, have a unique # address at the top, and load at the top of the page. For some reason when I previously tried to link to specific tabs it would load the page in different areas depending on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid default hash behavior (page jumping), I use a URL parameter instead. In your case this would result in, for example, http://nextadagency.com/theta/services.html?tab=3

```
  $(function() {
    // update URL parameter and browser history on manual tab select
    $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
      var myTab = $(ui.tab).attr('href').replace('#', '');
      var myParam = '?tab=' + myTab;
      window.history.pushState('Object', 'Title', myParam);
    });

    // get 'tab' URL parameter and select tab
    var param = $(document).getUrlParam('activity');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', param);
  });
```

This may be overkill for you, but at a minimum you need to stop default hash behavior, possible with `preventDefault()`.

Comment: how would I incorporate this into my current coding on the page?

Comment: if you look at my original Services page link you will see I incorporated your coding into the <head> section, what else needs to be done? Thanks

Comment: Since I wrote this answer I realized that I failed to mention the necessary inclusion of two files for handling URL parameters. Therefore, this answer is probably not a good option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url # (hash) and the tabs `selected` option:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
   selected: $('#tabs > ul > li > a[href='+window.location.hash+']').index()
});
```

Then when you go to something like:

http://nextadagency.com/theta/services.html#tabs1

It will load the tab that has ...

You can also add the hash to the url each time they change tabs:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
   select: function(e, ui){
      window.location.hash =  $(ui.tab).attr('href').replace(/\#/, '');
   }
});
```

Comment: How would I incorporate this into my current coding on the page?

Comment: Your page will already have some code that initiates tabs, like `$('#tabs').tabs({...})`. You just have to add `selected: $('#tabs > ul > li > a[href='+window.location.hash+']').index()` to that method call, Like in my example above.